# How to access a function from a class, called from a non-class function?

Tags: php, oop

**How to implement such a functionality in php?**

I am New to OOP concepts,
 please guide me the correct way.

```
class Sample{
  function getDetails($arg){
    return $arg;
  }
}

function getValue($value){
    $content= new Sample();
    $content->getDetails($value);
}
```

Comment: Whats wrong with your example?

Comment: i couldn't access that function from class @Kisaragi

Comment: Can you run this [fiddle](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/96d9c5302744a423538552e364faf36e8bc066fe)? I changed return to echo and works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine, I think you are missing returning the result

```
   class Sample{
      function getDetails($arg){
        return $arg;
      }
    }
    function getValue($value){
          $content= new Sample();
          $result = $content->getDetails($value);
          return $result;
    }

echo getValue( 'test' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant access that because it is not an "exposed" method, i.e, it is not a public method. Access control is part of php too.

```
   class Sample{
      public function getDetails($arg){
        return $arg;
      }
    }
    function getValue($value){
          $content= new Sample();
          $content->getDetails($value);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What I see you try to do, is call a method (a function defined in a class) from an ordinary function (a function not defined in a class).

It could be implemented as a static or non-static method.

**Static method** implementation will be as follows:

```
class Sample{
  public static function getDetails($arg){
    return $arg;
  }
}

function getValue($value){
      return Sample::getDetails($value);
}
```

**Non-static (instance) method** implementation will be as follows:

```
class Sample{
   public function getDetails($arg){
    return $arg;
  }
}

function getValue($value){
      $content= new Sample();
      return $content->getDetails($value);
}
```

I hope this is helpful.

Answer (score -2):

you can't use $this her, because function getValue() is out of class

Comment: Where are you referring to as "here"? The code sample doesn't use `$this` anywhere.

Comment: like that : class Sample{
      function getDetails($arg){
        return $arg;
      } 
    function getValue($value){
          $this->getDetails($value);
    }}

Comment: @Tndiaye Where did you see that code? That's significantly different from what the OP included in their question.

Comment: @duskwuff His question was how to access with $this, but he changed